# Elementor on WP - How can I avoid pop-up reappearing after the user clicked a button

Tags: wordpress, popup, elementor

I have the pop-up with 2 buttons for the users. One of them allows them to verify their age, and stay on the page. The pop-up disappears after the click, however it re-appears after a few seconds.

I have toggled "Avoid multiple pop-ups" to "yes" and it still reappears. Can anyone advise please?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to close the pop-up following the instruction from the Elementor website below: https://elementor.com/help/how-to-create-a-content-lock-popup/

> Edit the Yes Button Content:
>
> Link: Click the Dynamic icon  and choose Actions > Popup Click on
> Popup again Choose Close Popup and slide Don’t Show Again to Yes